# Group by using same key and join value with comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

I have the following sample data with dynamic key /value pair, i need to group them with same key , joining mutiple value by comma. I was able to extract unique keys on array and then stuck

input

```
[
          {
            "c1": "USA"
          },
          {
            "c2": "Korea"
          },
          {
            "c4": "japan"
          },
          {
            "c3": "india"
          },
          {
            "c1": "australia"
          },
          {
            "c2": "france"
          }
        ]
```

output

```
[
          {
            "c1": "USA,australia",
            "c2": "Korea,france",
            "c4": "japan",
            "c3": "india"
          }
        ]
```

```js
let data=[
      {
        "c1": "USA"
      },
      {
        "c2": "Korea"
      },
      {
        "c4": "japan"
      },
      {
        "c3": "india"
      },
      {
        "c1": "australia"
      },
      {
        "c2": "france"
      }
    ]
    
    var output = Object.keys(data).map(element => {
    
      var ret = Object.keys(data[element]);
      
      return ret;
    
    })
    let c=[...new Set(output.flat())];
    console.log(c);
```

How to join the values by comma from the unique array i got,  i think i am halfway

Comment: manipulate `map()` to build and return  new object comparing keys. you're half way there.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to output a new organized object with the help of your `map()` function.

didn't check the code -  but it should look something like this.

```
 let dataNew = {};
 var output = Object.keys(data).map(element => {
      if (typeof( dataNew[element] ) === 'undefined') {
        dataNew[element] = data[element]
      } else {
        dataNew[element] += `,${data[element]}`;
      }
      return dataNew;
    })
```

like this you are creating a new object with comas in unified values.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i went back and de-duped the final Array.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "c1": "USA"
  },
  {
    "c2": "Korea"
  },
  {
    "c4": "japan"
  },
  {
    "c3": "india"
  },
  {
    "c1": "australia"
  },
  {
    "c2": "france"
  }
]

let endData = [{}]

data.forEach(d => {
  const [dataKey] = Object.keys(d)
  const relatedValues = data.map(d => dataKey in d ? d[dataKey] : null).filter(Boolean)
  const combinedValues = [d[dataKey], ...relatedValues]
  
  const unique = endData.find(d => Object.keys(d)[0] === dataKey) === undefined
  if (unique) endData[0][dataKey] = `${[...new Set(combinedValues)]}`
})

console.log(endData)
```

Comment: it has duplicated values

Comment: @eagerleaner that better?

Comment: Your expected output is an array with an object inside (like i have provided) is that necessary? or can `endData` jut be an Object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Array.reduce prototype

```js
let data=[
      {
        "c1": "USA"
      },
      {
        "c2": "Korea"
      },
      {
        "c4": "japan"
      },
      {
        "c3": "india"
      },
      {
        "c1": "australia"
      },
      {
        "c2": "france"
      }
    ]

const combinedData = data.reduce((memory, current) => {
 const currentKeys = Object.keys(current);
 const found = memory.find(m => 
  Object.keys(m).some(key => currentKeys.includes(key))
 );

 if (found) {
  const key = Object.keys(found).pop();
  found[key] = `${found[key]},${current[key]}`;
    } else {
  memory.push(current);
    }

 return memory;

}, []);

console.log(combinedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the key value pairs, flatten them (as it does not matter wether the keys where in the same object or not), then merge using another object:

```
 const result = input
  .map(Object.entries)
  .flat()
  .reduce((obj, [k, v]) => ((obj[k] = obj[k] ? (obj[k] + ", " + v) : v), obj), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your code:
iterate over each value of Set `c`, then filter the data items that have the same key, then merge them with `join (',')`.

```js
let data=[
      {
        "c1": "USA"
      },
      {
        "c2": "Korea"
      },
      {
        "c4": "japan"
      },
      {
        "c3": "india"
      },
      {
        "c1": "australia"
      },
      {
        "c2": "france"
      }
    ]
    
    var output = Object.keys(data).map(element => {
    
      var ret = Object.keys(data[element]);
      
      return ret;
    
    })
    let c=[...new Set(output.flat())];
    
    /* Join equals */
    const n = []; 
    c.forEach( (it, idx) => {
      n.push({});
      n[idx][it] = data.filter(its => it === Object.keys(its)[0])
                  .map( its => Object.values(its)[0])
                  .join(',');
    })
    console.log(n);
```